# MongoDB check for existing value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, post, npm

How do I check if a mongo/mongoose value exists before continuing in a post route?

My (partial) Mongoose model looks like this:

```
 reserved: {type: Boolean, default: false}
 module.exports = mongoose.model("Rentals", rentalsSchema);
```

I've been trying to check to see if reserved is true in this way without any luck

NOTE: As you'll see below this needs to work for each rentals ID so it will need to findById somehow.

```
router.put("/:id/reserve", middleware.checkRentalsStatus, function(req, res){


     //checking here for existing value
     //checking here for existing value

     if(Rentals.reserved == true){
            res.redirect("back");
            console.log('TAKEN!')
        } else {


 // Token is created using Stripe.js or Checkout!
// Get the payment token submitted by the form:
 var token = req.body.stripeToken; // Using Express

// Charge the user's card:
  var charge = stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 19500,
  currency: "usd",
  description: "",
  source: token,
}, function(err, charge) {
     if(err){
            req.flash("error", err.message);
            res.redirect("back");
        } else {


    var reservedby = req.body.reservedby;
    var reserved = true;
    var reservedemail = req.body.reservedemail;
    var newReservation = {reserved: reserved, reservedby: reservedby, reservedemail: reservedemail }
    Rentals.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: newReservation}, function(err, rentals){
        if(err){
            req.flash("error", err.message);
            res.redirect("back");
        } else {

            req.flash("success","It's reserved for you. Thank you!");
            res.redirect("/rentals/" + rentals._id);
        }
    });

}
});

  console.log('charged')
});
```

How would I change my code to check if reserved is true prior to finishing the post route? (I'm trying to check if a rental is available on a reserve route in the back end. )

Comment: please provide full code.

Comment: What is Rentals in this case & how did you retrieve value from Mongo.

Comment: Just try like this which i usually i try it in my code. if(Rentals.reserved){
        res.redirect("back");
        console.log('TAKEN!')
    } else {
    // continue with post route

Comment: print value of Rentals.reserved before entering this if condition.

Comment: did it worked for you.

Comment: i have done it now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the answer. Best way is to create a middleware to check. The issue with the other answers is they do not find the renal's ID. Rentals.findByID is the key to making this work. :)

```
//CHECK Rentals HAS NOT BEEN RENTED
middlewareObj.checkRentalsStatus = function(req, res, next){
    Rentals.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundRentals){
    if (err){
        res.redirect("back");
    }

  if (foundRentals.reserved){
            req.flash("error", 'Oh no! It looks like someone else JUST rented this location. Your credit card was not charged.');
            res.redirect("back");
} else {
next();
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly check if/else condition like this

```
  if(Rentals.reserved )
     { res.redirect("back"); console.log('TAKEN!') } 
        else { // continue with post route 
       }
```

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi Your schema defines `reserved` as a `Boolean`. A `Boolean` is either `true` or `false`. There's no need for an equality check.